# PHP run a script when a session expires

Tags: php, session, e-commerce

I have a cart application with unique items with qty 1 - I need to deplete the stock qty when a user puts one in the basket to avoid someone else buying it. Problem is, that if they abandon the cart without buying I need to put the item back in stock.

Is there a way I can replenish the stock when the cart session expires?  ie run a script to replace the stock.

Comment: That seems a bit strange to do it that way.  I could, for example, add all your items to my cart.  If your normal session is 20 min you would have no stock for 20 min.  Why not just have it remove the stock when someone checks out? You could then also have a check when they click check out to make sure it is still in stock.

Comment: I wouldn’t remove them from stock when putting them into the cart but only when they are actually bought.

Comment: Thanks, I agree but it isn't my decision!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `session_set_save_handler` to create a custom session-handling class.
When you do this, you can decide other actions that need to run either when the garbage collector is called or at session destroy. If you decide to work with the garbage collector, ensure that you also know the values for `session.gc_divisor` and `session.gc_probability` and also understand what they do (these set the probability that the garbage collector will run).

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the need of cron jobs; keep it simple:

1. A user picks places a object in his/hers basket
2. Timestamp for "placing object in basket" is stored in the database, and a timeout timestamp is stored too. For example `(time() + (60*20))`
3. User closes webpage
4. On every pageload you do a simple mysql-query to check if timeout-timestamps are smaller than the current timestamp. If the query returns a result, delete from basket and put back in slot.

(This require that you update some sort of "last activity" in the database too)

Should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Create a database table to track session activity, say `sessions`. In it, put at least the fields `session_id` and a DATETIME or TIME field called `last_activity`.

If you don't have so already, also create a `carts` table that holds the content of the cart (like `product_id` and `quantity`) and has a link to the `session_id`. Then, there are 2 scenarios:

1. The user finishes the order, just "wipe" the rows in the `carts` table belonging to their session.
2. The user abandons the cart, call a cronjob that checks to see if the `last_activity` value is more then you want it to be (say, more then an hour ago). Make that script re-stock your supply with the quantity that was in the cart.

Note that you will need to update the `last_activity` field in your bootstrap/loader (a mechanism that is triggered on every loaded page).